# Can I Quick Deploy a SharePoint Solution via CMD/Grunt/SublimeText?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sublimetext2

I am currently working on a SharePoint site, I am trying to optimize my workflow. I work on the front-end, and I really don't like using Visual Studio 2010 as it is very slow. I prefer Sublime Text for doing my front-end work, as this is the editor i normally use.

I use Grunt.js to automate build SCSS and JS files, it's triggered via a Visual Studio 2010  Pre-Build Event. This works fine for the build process but not so well for my development process.

The Pre-Build Event copies my `/_layout/` folder to the servers `/_layout/` folder. The problem is with user-controls ect, these are not in identical folders, they might be in one folder on the project and another one when deployed.

I can edit my files in Sublime Text, but I then have to go into Visual Studio 2010 and Quick Deploy using the [CKS-Dev addon](http://cksdev.codeplex.com/). It would be nice if I could run a command in CMD that would trigger a quick deploy.

Do you have any solutions to this? Or any knowledge that would leverage my workflow?